# Hadoop services are not getting stated if i use particular zlib library

Tags: hadoop, service, zlib

I'm trying to use different zlib library with hadoop. When i'm using a particular library, hadoop services are not getting started. Services are starting properly if i use different library. The only difference between the libraries are, not working one using a device file to send data to kernel driver for compression. Where could be the issue ? and also where to look for the error log in hadoop.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more specific details. What version of hadoop, distribution, What is the version of zlib etc.

Comment: To find hadoop logs use the trick `find /var/log -mmin -1`. It will show you all files changed in the last minute.